# Validar StreamReader duas vezes

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Recebo um arquivo .csv no meu *Controller*. Este arquivo pode conter dois *templates*, com 2 ou 5 linhas.

Primeiro tenho que fazer a validação para verificar se o arquivo contém 5 linhas:

```
 var arquivo = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream, Encoding.UTF7);
                var arquivoValida = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream, Encoding.UTF7);

   if (this.TipoArquivoLCCP(arquivoValida, out listaRetorno, out numColunasLCCP, out isLCCP)) { }


 private bool TipoArquivoLCCP(StreamReader arquivoLCCP, out object listaRetorno, out int numColunasLCCP, out bool isLCCP)
 {

     while (arquivoLCCP.Peek() > -1)
     { /* Verificação */ }
```

Caso esta verificação retorne `false`, vou pro segundo método que faz a outra verificação:

```
  if (!isLCCP && this.ValidarArquivo(arquivo, model.TipoPagina, model.Pais, out listaRetorno, out numColunas))
  { ... }
```

Método `ValidarArquivo()`:

```
 private bool ValidarArquivo(StreamReader arquivo, Enumeradores.TipoPaginaUploadColeta tipoPagina, string idPais, out object listaRetorno, out int numColunas)
 {

     while (arquivo.Peek() > -1)
     { ... }
```

O problema é que o comando

```
 while (arquivo.Peek() > -1) { ... }
```

sempre retorna -1 e não consigo entrar dentro das validações.

Como podem ver, criei duas variáveis diferentes que recebem meu arquivo:

```
var arquivo = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream, Encoding.UTF7);
var arquivoValida = new StreamReader(model.Arquivo.InputStream, Encoding.UTF7);
```

e uso cada uma delas em um método, mas mesmo assim não funciona.

Comment: No final do primeiro método que faz a validação incluir
model.Arquivo.InputStream.Position = 0;

e funcionou

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Conforme comentário do autor da pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/201364/validar-streamreader-duas-vezes#comment412763_201364), há um problema de `Position` na hora de ler o arquivo submetido por formulário:

```
model.Arquivo.InputStream.Position = 0;
```

Isto porque

```
model.Arquivo.Peek() == -1
```

O que indica que a posição de leitura do arquivo está sempre no final dele após o final do primeiro método.